# Temp Table Populate WHILE/Cursor

Tags: sql-server, database, while-loop, cursor, dynamic-programming

Recently I've been working on a SQL Server job that performs our weekly backups. As part of a business requirement, these databases need to be backed up from smallest to largest in the most accurate way possible.

I've managed to do this with the `sp_msforeachdb` stored proc using code I found to help finding database size:

```
DROP TABLE #temp1
CREATE TABLE #temp1
(name varchar(50),
database_size varchar(50),
Freespace varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #temp1(name,database_size,Freespace)
EXEC sp_msforeachdb
'use ?;SELECT database_name = db_name()
,database_size = ltrim(str((convert(DECIMAL(15, 2), dbsize) + convert(DECIMAL(15, 2), logsize)) * 8192 / 1048576, 15, 2))
,''unallocated space'' = ltrim(str((
CASE 
WHEN dbsize >= reservedpages
THEN (convert(DECIMAL(15, 2), dbsize) - convert(DECIMAL(15, 2), reservedpages)) * 8192 / 1048576
ELSE 0
END
), 15, 2))
FROM (
SELECT dbsize = sum(convert(BIGINT, CASE 
WHEN type = 0
THEN size
ELSE 0
END))
,logsize = sum(convert(BIGINT, CASE 
WHEN type <> 0
THEN size
ELSE 0
END))
FROM sys.database_files
) AS files
,(
SELECT reservedpages = sum(a.total_pages)
,usedpages = sum(a.used_pages)
,pages = sum(CASE 
WHEN it.internal_type IN (
202
,204
,211
,212
,213
,214
,215
,216
)
THEN 0
WHEN a.type <> 1
THEN a.used_pages
WHEN p.index_id < 2
THEN a.data_pages
ELSE 0
END)
FROM sys.partitions p
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a
ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT JOIN sys.internal_tables it
ON p.object_id = it.object_id
) AS partitions'

SELECT [name] AS [DB_Name], ((CAST (database_size AS DECIMAL(10,2))) - (CAST (Freespace AS DECIMAL (10,2)))) AS Used
FROM #temp1
WHERE [name] <> 'tempdb'
ORDER BY Used
```

I think understandably, my company doesn't put undocumented stored procs in production code, so I've been trying to find a work-around.

The logic I came up with to get around this was to first create a temporary table (`#temp`) and populate it with a consecutive ID# and all of the database IDs and names on the server from the `sys.databases` table. This table ended up looking like this:

[First couple rows of `#temp`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bIRt.png)

Once this table is created, I've been attempting to loop through the databases in `#temp` to `UPDATE` the 'Used' column (contains the # of pages used in the database as pulled from `SUM(used_pages)` in `sys.allocation_units`). After this, I already have a functional cursor that will go through `#temp` and run the backups in the order we need using `ORDER BY`. So essentially in this 3 part process, I'm just stuck on the step that populates the used space in `#temp`.

To avoid the terror that can be cursors any more than I already have, I was originally trying to use a `WHILE` loop to populate my #temp table. Here's what I came up with:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @BigSQL NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(100);

SET @sql = 'UPDATE tempdb..#temp
            SET Used = (SELECT SUM(a.used_pages)
            FROM sys.partitions p
            INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
            LEFT JOIN sys.internal_tables it ON p.object_id = it.object_id)';
SET @dbName = N'master'

DECLARE @db_name VARCHAR(100)
    ,@db_size DECIMAL(15, 2)
    ,@db_freespace DECIMAL(15, 2);

IF object_id ('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp

--index me
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    DB_ID INT,
    [Name] VARCHAR(50)
    ,Used VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT INTO #temp (DB_ID, [Name])
        SELECT database_id, [Name]
        FROM sys.databases

--#temp check 1
SELECT *
FROM #temp


    DECLARE @min INT
            , @max INT
            , @cur INT;
    DECLARE @executionString VARCHAR(MAX),
            @DB VARCHAR(50);

    SELECT @min = MIN(ID),
           @max = MAX(ID),
           @cur = MIN(ID) 
    FROM #temp;


            WHILE (@cur <= @max)

                BEGIN

                    SELECT @dbName = [Name] FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = @cur;

                    SET @BigSQL = 'USE ' + @dbName + '; EXEC sp_executesql N'''+ @sql + '''';

                        EXEC(@BigSQL);

                    SET @cur = @cur + 1;

                END

--#temp check 2
SELECT *
FROM #temp
```

I was never able to get this to work because from what I understand, variables won't work in a `USE ['database']` statement in dynamic SQL and the [solution](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/5108/database-use-issues-with-dynamic-sql.html) proposed by Tom Staab using `sp_executesql` isn't working for me. Basically what ended up happening was every time I execute the code, the number of pages used in the first database referenced would populate down to every database in my `#temp` table. Because of this, I figured the issue might be in the loop and transitioning over to a cursor might help. I wrote the following:

```
DECLARE @used INTEGER
    , @Name VARCHAR(100);

IF object_id ('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp

--index me
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , DB_ID INT
    , [Name] VARCHAR(50)
    ,Used VARCHAR(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO #temp (DB_ID, [Name])
        SELECT database_id, [Name]
        FROM sys.databases

--#temp check 1
SELECT *
FROM #temp


DECLARE temp_populate CURSOR FOR
SELECT [Name]
FROM #temp

    OPEN temp_populate

    FETCH NEXT FROM temp_populate
    INTO @Name

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

            SELECT @used = SUM(used_pages)
                FROM sys.allocation_units

        IF((SELECT Used FROM #temp WHERE [Name] = @Name) IS NULL)
            UPDATE #temp
            SET Used = @used
            WHERE [Name] = @Name;

        ELSE
        PRINT ''

    END
    CLOSE temp_populate

DEALLOCATE temp_populate

--#temp check 2
SELECT *
FROM #temp
```

The issue I'm getting here is that the first database in the `#temp` table (in this case master) just gets evaluated over and over again until I cancel the query. If I `SELECT * FROM #temp` after canceling, the first row of the table populates correctly, but all the rest remain `NULL`.

I know this is quite the extensive post, but I've been working on this a couple days now and honestly would appreciate a fresh pair of eyes or someone who is more experienced with SQL who could propose a different method entirely for what I'm trying to do. Thanks so much for reading all this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query to get the size of databases

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , DB_ID INT
    , [Name] VARCHAR(50)
    , Used DECIMAL(8,2)
    )

INSERT INTO #temp (DB_ID, [Name], Used)
SELECT 
     MF.database_id
    ,database_name = DB_NAME(database_id)
    , total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
FROM sys.master_files MF
GROUP BY database_id
ORDER BY total_size_mb DESC


--#temp check 1
SELECT *
FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was never able to get this to work because from what I've learned,
>   USE ['database'] can't be used in dynamic SQL

You are able to use `USE` in [dynamic SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185047/114601)

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant you can't use variables in a USE statement. I'll edit that now.

Comment: but you, see the link

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel - especially if you do not have significant tsql skills. Use Ola's solutions [here](https://ola.hallengren.com/) - which are widely used, well-written, and well-regarded.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I did look through the Ola website for a bit, but I couldn't find anything referencing what I was trying to do. Maybe it just missed it. :)